# I'm trying to do a def statement but can't get it to work no matter what I try

Tags: python, module

I am doing it as a def statement to import it into another module for a school assignment for a loan calculator but can't figure out what I am doing wrong or how to get it to work. I am a beginner still and couldn't find anything in my text book.

```
    l = float(input("What loan amount would you like to take out?"))

    def loan_amount(variable):
       if l < 500:
          print("Sorry we don't offer loans below 500")
       elif l >= 500 and l < 3000:
           print("help")
       elif l >= 3000 and l < 5000:
           print("me")
       elif l >= 5000:
    return loan_amount 

    print(loan_amount(variable))
```

Comment: indent `return loan_amount` and there's nothing to return so use `return None`

Comment: In Python it is very important to indent your code properly. Indentation is part of the syntax.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you want to return the result instead of print it.

This code may work better:

```
amt = float(input("What loan amount would you like to take out?"))

def loan_amount(l): # received loan amount
   if l < 500:
       return "Sorry we don't offer loans below 500"
   elif l >= 500 and l < 3000:
       return "help"
   elif l >= 3000 and l < 5000:
       return "me"
   elif l >= 5000:
       return "really big" 

print(loan_amount(amt))  # pass amount to function
```